# Syntax Highlight "quebrado" no CSS

Tags: debate

Faz algum tempo que venho observando que o Highlight nos códigos CSS parece "quebrado".

Apenas algumas propriedades bem específicas é que recebem cor e no geral o código fica todo preto.

Exemplo comparando o SO-en com o SO-pt:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se a remoção das cores nas propriedades foi proposital ou algum equívoco, mas acho que deixar pelo menos como está no SO-en ajuda bastante no entendimento do que foi escrito.

Talvez ir até um pouco além do SO-pt e dando cores mais vivas (baseadas em outras linguagens do SO) aos seletores seria interessante também. O que acham?

Comment: A pergunta desse exemplo tem a tag CSS? Parece um exemplo de código interpretado como HTML ou JS. Se você forçar `<!-- language: lang-css -->`, deve ficar correto.

Comment: @bfavaretto [Possui a tag CSS sim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30534/desabilitar-todos-os-inputs-de-um-form-utilizando-apenas-css)

Comment: Tentei usar `<!-- language: lang-css -->` e também não funcionou.

Comment: As tags de HTML estavam "ganhando" da de CSS para o syntax highlighting. Veja agora sem elas (recarregue a página da pergunta).

Comment: @bfavaretto Foi isso mesmo, agora está funcionando corretamente. Interessante, não sabia que até a ordem das tags interferia na linguagem assimilada dos códigos.

Comment: Não é bem a ordem, algumas tags têm precedência sobre as outras, mas não sei direito como isso funciona.

Comment: Isso é um [tag:debate] ou era um [tag:bug]?

Comment: O `<!-- language: lang-xxxxx -->` fica dentro do bloco de código?

Comment: @Patrick Acima do bloco, sem indent.

Comment: Existe alguma lista que mostra todos os *highlights* disponíveis?